# Swipe button in JSON schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

There is a variable which can be 0 or 1. I would like to set in JSON schema as a swipe button, not as a list. So it could be set to on / off. How could I implement this in schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON Schema describes validation and hyperlinks (JSON Hyper-Schema).  It does not describe user interface elements.  You will have to describe your user interface elements with something other than JSON Schema.

There are a couple of tools out there that generate a form based on a JSON Schema, but how they do so is defined by the specific tool in use, not JSON Schema.

There has been discussion about creating an official JSON Schema UI specification, but no such thing exists yet.